# Updating the text of a label inside a UIViewControler from a function that runs automatically when a midi note is played

Tags: ios, swift

I have a callbackInstrument on my sequence struct that runs a function every time a midi note is played. Inside that function I need it to update the ChordLabel.text inside the PlayerPage UIViewControler. I don't know how to access that label from within that function. Thank you.

```
class PlayerPage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ChordLabel: UILabel!
...
}

struct sequence{
let callbackInstr = MIDICallbackInstrument(callback: myCallBack(a:noteNumber:velocity:))
...
}

func myCallBack(a:UInt8, noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity) -> () {
    if noteNumber > 0 {  // if noteOn
        ChordLabel.text = noteNumber   
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call myCallBack method ?

Comment: It is called automatically when a note plays on the sequencer... its in the struct I posted in the question... and that is the line that associates with the function.

Comment: Sorry. Its not in the player pageclass... it is outside on a separate struct...